# Writing Data to Poll Invalid Socket Causes Uncatchable Exception

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, server

I am working on a game server that uses sockets and implemented a polling function that sends the message "[POLL]" over all player sockets in a lobby every second to notify the player clients that their connection is still alive.

If I disconnect on the client-side the socket is still polled with no errors, however, if I create a new connection with the same client (Gets a new FD and is added to the map as a second player), the whole server crashes without any exceptions/warnings/messages when it attempts to write to the previous socket FD. My call to Write on the socket is wrapped in a try/catch that doesn't catch any exceptions and, when debugging using gdb, I am not given any error messaging.

This is the Socket Write function:

```
int Socket::Write(ByteArray const& buffer)
{
    if (!open)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    // Convert buffer to raw char array
    char* raw = new char[buffer.v.size()];
    for (int i=0; i < buffer.v.size(); i++)
    {
        raw[i] = buffer.v[i];
    }

    // Perform the write operation
    int returnValue = write(GetFD(), raw, buffer.v.size()); // <- Crashes program
    if (returnValue <= 0)
    {
        open = false;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

And this is the Poll function (Players are stored in a map of uint -> Socket*):

```
/*
    Polls all connected players to tell them
    to keep their connections alive.
*/
void Lobby::Poll()
{
    playerMtx.lock();
    for (auto it = players.begin(); it != players.end(); it++)
    {
        try
        {
            if (it->second != nullptr && it->second->IsOpen())
            {
                it->second->Write("[POLL]");
            }
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to write to " << it->first << std::endl;
        }
    }
    playerMtx.unlock();
}
```

I would expect to see the "Failed to write to " message but instead the entire server program exits with no messaging. What could be happening here?

Comment: Is `write` a C function? If so, it won’t throw any exceptions, so the calling code won’t catch any exceptions if it goes astray.

Comment: Totally unrelated: You can probably replace `write(GetFD(), raw, buffer.v.size());` with something like `write(GetFD(), buffer.v.data(), buffer.v.size());` and save yourself a leaked memory allocation (`char* raw = new char[buffer.v.size()];`) and all of the copying.

Comment: Hmm I think you're right. I found the article for this function here [link](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write)

But the documentation doesn't specify any exception throwing - only that I'll get an error as my result int that I can then process. For some reason my program exits without passing the write line.

Comment: Nothing obvious wrong in `write(GetFD(), raw, buffer.v.size())`. Make sure `GetFD()` returns a valid handle (and make sure you haven't accidentally closed it ([Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and all that)

Comment: @user4581301 Is there some way to validate the handle I get from GetFD() - even though the client stopped listening at their end I am still receiving a positive integer for my fd and when I run a fcntl - F_GETFD (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) against it is still marked as valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to find a reason for the program crashing in the call to write but I was able to find a workaround.

I perform a [poll](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) operation on the file descriptor prior to calling write and I query the POLLNVAL event. If I receive a nonzero value, the FD is now invalid.

```
// Check if FD is valid
struct pollfd pollFd;
pollFd.fd = GetFD();
pollFd.events = POLLNVAL;
if (poll(&pollFd, 1, 0) > 0)
{
    open = false;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: This also brings up another good idea: [Using `epoll` to monitor your file descriptors](https://linux.die.net/man/4/epoll)

Comment: Invest some time in figuring out what's killing your descriptors, though.  Crom only knows what ever surprises the answer could resolve. Don't assume one bug == one observable result.